# Installing python module on a vm

Tags: python, module, remote-access

I'm trying to install a module (already installed on my computer) on remote vm. The vm's os may be windows or linux. 
Let's say it is for the sake of it,  the module's name is "netifaces".

Is it possible to accomplish that from my computer  using python code?  Maybe rpyc?  Some kind of tcp connection?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using pip yet?

Comment: The installation should be initiated from my personal computer

Comment: Yes, so you SSH in and run pip. You can automate that with fabric.

Comment: Yeah it's a good idea, but on my test vm(windows) im getting the error : "unable to find vcvarsall.bat"